# Find permutations which also match other constraints

Tags: python, constraints, permutation, python-itertools

Given the following list:

```
dbset = [[{'id': '10556', 'nation': 'France', 'worth': '70'}], [{'id': '14808', 'nation': 'France', 'worth': '65'}], [{'id': '11446', 'nation': 'Ghana', 'worth': '69'}], [{'id': '11419', 'nation': 'France', 'worth': '69'}], [{'id': '11185', 'nation': 'Ghana', 'worth': '69'}], [{'id': '1527', 'nation': 'Ghana', 'worth': '64'}], [{'id': '12714', 'nation': 'Moldova', 'worth': '67'}], [{'id': '2855', 'nation': 'Moldova', 'worth': '63'}], [{'id': '9620', 'nation': 'Moldova', 'worth': '71'}]]
```

I know how to find all permutations of length 4 with:

```
from itertools import permutations
perms = permutations(dbset,4)
```

Now comes the part where I struggle; I want the maximum times a nation is in the permutation to be equal to 2 and I also would like the total worth to be above 300.

**---Update---**

I managed to get this working for the limited sample with limited permutations. The sample size however, is a set with over 16000 records and the permutation size is 11. As of yet, I am still executing it for the first time with 2 criteria: avg worth = 80 and nation occurrence <= 5.

It's been running for over an hour now... any way to improve?

Comment: If the data is ordered somehow you may be able to do something faster with a tree-based search with pruning. However, if there's no structure to the data then I'm not sure there's anything better than filtering.

Comment: well, I can spend some cpu time on re-structuring the data; at the moment it's just a json file. what kind of structure would you suggest? Keep in mind that the sample dataset is basic; the source is basically a dict with 40+ attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is as simple as:

```
perms = list(permutations(dbset,4))
out = [x in perms if CONDITION]
```

The second condition is as simple as:

```
out = [x for x in perms if sum([int(country[0]["worth"]) for country in x]) >= 300]
```

Note that this will be empty in your case, since the maximum worth of any nation is 71, and 300/4 = 75.

I'll let you figure out the way to implement the first condition, but it is very similar. Note: `and` statements are your friend!

Comment: Thank you for the hints; I didn't really check the sample set to match against the value 300, but I get the idea. 

@QWERTYL is there a way to improve the speed on this when I have a dataset of size 1863 and my permutation length is 11? It's tediously slow.

Comment: I'm glad to be of help! Unfortunately, as far as I know, there is no way to speed this up using libraries. You'd have to write your own backtracking function to find all the permutations and eliminate permutations that won't work early using pruning. See this for more details: http://comscigate.com/Books/ADM/BOOK/BOOK2/NODE88.HTM . If you don't like that particular link, I'd just look up "Backtracking".

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that tests your conditions. Then filter the permutations using it.

```
from collections import Counter

def valid_permutation(perm):
    if sum(int(p['worth']) for p in perm) <= 300:
        return False
    counts = Counter(p['nation'] for p in perm)
    return counts.most_common()[0][1] <= 2

perms = filter(valid_permutation, permutations([d[0] for d in dbset], 4))
```

Comment: Unfortunately this gives me a TypeError exception; list indices must be integers or slices, not str on the line with "counts = "

Comment: Why does `dbset` have nested lists instead of just being a list of dictionaries? Can the nested lists have more than one element?

Comment: None of your permutations have total worth > 300. The highest value of worth is 71, so if you have 4 of them, the highest total worth will be 284.

Comment: I've changed the code to extra the first element of each nested list and use that.

Comment: The reason dbset is as it is, is because of the file I am reading the values from. As for the total value exceeding 300, I just threw that number in and didn't look at the sample set. I can take 278 as well.

Comment: If the lists always have just one dict in them, my updated code should work.